# Implementing boolean similar to built-in boolean

Tags: clojure

I am working through some Clojure tutorials and one of the problems is: Implement (boolean x), which works like the built-in boolean function: for nil and false, it returns false, and for all other values it returns true. You can use if in its implementation, but not the build-in boolean.

I cannot figure out how to do this with just the if statement. This works, but is there a better way?

```
(defn boolean [x]
   (cond
     (= x nil) false
     (= x false) false
     :else true))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nil` and `false` are both 'falsey' (i.e. are equivalent to `false` in a boolean context) so you can do:

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (if x true false))
```

`if` expressions are of the form `(if condition true-expr false-expr)` so if `condition` evaluates to `true` the entire expression evaluates to `true-expr` otherwise `false-expr`. So if `x` is `truthy` (i.e. not `nil` or `false`) the expression will evaluate to `true`. If `x` is `falsey` (`nil` and `false` are the only falsey values in clojure) then false is returned.

Comment: They don't *evaluate* to false; rather, they *are* "falsey".

Comment: I have seen that solution before but I cannot figure out what it's saying exactly. Could you explain what is going on inside the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this?

```
(defn my-boolean [val]
  (not (or (nil? val) (false? val))))
```